# Octal converts to Hexadecimal wrong

Tags: java, string, binary, hex, octal

I've been trying to code a program that will convert an octal to binary, and then hexadecimal, but the problem is that I'm getting the wrong answer. The code for actually converting is as follows:

```
    user_input=user_input.replace("0", "00");
    user_input=user_input.replace("1", "01");
    user_input=user_input.replace("2", "10");
    user_input=user_input.replace("3", "11");
    user_input=user_input.replace("4", "100");
    user_input=user_input.replace("5", "101");
    user_input=user_input.replace("6", "110");
    user_input=user_input.replace("7", "111");

    if (!(user_input.length()-1 % 4 ==0)){
        user_input = "00" + user_input; }


    user_input=user_input.replace("0000", "0");
    user_input=user_input.replace("0001", "1");
    user_input=user_input.replace("0010", "2");
    user_input=user_input.replace("0011", "3");
    user_input=user_input.replace("0100", "4");
    user_input=user_input.replace("0101", "5");
    user_input=user_input.replace("0110", "6");
    user_input=user_input.replace("0111", "7");
    user_input=user_input.replace("1000", "8");
    user_input=user_input.replace("1001", "9");
    user_input=user_input.replace("1010", "A");
    user_input=user_input.replace("1011", "B");
    user_input=user_input.replace("1100", "C");
    user_input=user_input.replace("1101", "D");
    user_input=user_input.replace("1110", "E");
    user_input=user_input.replace("1111", "F");
```

My key uses the number 1057, which should convert to 22F, but I'm getting an output of 12F

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you print the intermediate results and compare them with what you expect?

Comment: You sometimes convert octal input to a 2-digit binary string, sometimes to a 3-digit binary string.  I guess that may be related.

Comment: Also there can be "unwanted" replacements in the second part.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this instead

```
int user_input_dec = Integer.parseInt(user_input,8);
String hex = Integer.toHexString(user_input_dec);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. When converting 0-3 from octal to binary, you need that leading 0. Currently, your code changes octal `10` to binary `0100`, which is incorrect (you've turned 8 into 4).
2. When you parse from binary to hexadecimal, if you just do a replace, the result of parsing `0000` or `0001` may get parsed in a subsequent call. For example, if you have `00000010`, it'll first change it to `00010`, then `10` and stop, when it was supposed to be parsed into `2`.

While it's possible to patch these up, @asantaballa is right, `Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(user_input, 8))` does the same thing as what you were trying to get your code to do.